# Get index of selected row to use in prepare for segue

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

I want to pass different arrays from one ViewController to another based on which row is selected.
How can I get the index for selected row?
I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
let toDetailVCSegue = "ToDetailVCSegue"

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: toDetailVCSegue, sender: indexPath)
    }



     func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: IndexPath?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == toDetailVCSegue
        {
        let destination = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    destination.itemArray = namesArray
                    print("test")
                }
                if indexPath.row == 1 {
                    destination.itemArray = scoresArray
                }
                if indexPath.row == 2 {
                    destination.itemArray = timesArray
                }
                if indexPath.row == 3 {
                    destination.itemArray = completedArray
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If all you are doing in `didSelectRowAt` is passing along the selected row, you don't need it at all.  Just get the selected row in `prepare(for:sender:)` with `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.  That is an optional, so unwrap it safely in the usual ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **must not** change the signature of `prepare(for` otherwise it's not going to be called. The `sender` parameter must be `Any?`

Cast the `sender` parameter to `IndexPath` and I recommend a `switch` statement

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == toDetailVCSegue {
        let destination = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        switch indexPath.row {
          case 0: destination.itemArray = namesArray
          case 1: destination.itemArray = scoresArray
          case 2: destination.itemArray = timesArray             
          case 3: destination.itemArray = completedArray
          default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. What if I later want to for example pass a `heightForRowAt`parameter? How would that be done with this kind of solution?

Comment: `Any` means you can pass anything you like even arrays, dictionaries or still more complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let toDetailVCSegue = "ToDetailVCSegue"

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: toDetailVCSegue, sender: indexPath)
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if  
        let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController, 
        let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0: destination.itemArray = namesArray
            case 1: destination.itemArray = scoresArray
            case 2: destination.itemArray = timesArray             
            case 3: destination.itemArray = completedArray
            default: break

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't change the signature of the `prepare` function. That would be 'function overloading', so basically a different function that will not be called.

Comment: Yea I did notice that, just forgot to remove the latter when I copied the code. This is the reason I had declared `if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath`. Thank you for pointing it out though, updated my answer! @TmKVU